# Openshift - alias on domain name not showing

Tags: url, openshift

So i have gone through all the suggested tutorials on mapping my domain  to  open shift app and this is where i am.

1. I assume that i have configured my CNAME correctly as when i type my domain name into a browser i am taken to my open shift app.

> ie www.mydomain.com takes me to my open shift app...

So thats correct...

1. I then set up an alias on my open shift app `i.e. www.mydomain.com`

i run rhc app show (`myOpenshiftapp`)

and i am shown the following...

```
Domain:     myDomain
  Created:    Aug 31  2:36 PM
  Gears:      1 (defaults to small)
  Git URL:    ----
  SSH:        -----
  Deployment: auto (on git push)
  Aliases:    www.mydomain.com
```

Therefore i assume that its configured correctly, yet when i type my domain name in a browser i get taken to my open shift app and i see `my .rhcloud.com` name showing not the alias ???

Comment: Try different browser

Comment: What type of application is it?  What is the actual domain name?  Are you sure you setup a cname and not a redirect for your domain name?  You might need to setup your application code to respond to your domain name instead of your rhcloud.com domain, sometimes a redirect can happen there also.

Comment: I have the same issue. Everything is set up correctly and when I enter 'myboughtdomain' in the browser it takes me to my app on openshift, but shows the openshift url instead of 'myboughtdomain'. I also tried with different browsers. Now I tried this whole operation on heroku and everything works fine there

Answer (score 1):

You have to use https://pointhq.com/ for integartion of your openshift app which provide free nameserver for one domain. any problem with that let me know:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for the longest time.

To fix it, in openshift, I added both versions of my domain name: www.domainame.com AND domainname.com (without the WWW)

Also, in my CNAME entries on my domain name hosting I had the following:

domainname.com -> points to app-name.redhat.com 
www.domainname.com -> points to app-name.redhat.com